# Need to get middle part of path

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a path like this

```
apples/oranges/bananas
```

I need to get the middle item in the path, in this case oranges.

What is the best way to do it? I can do it myself using strpos and substr but I imagine there is a better way...

Comment: You could try using `explode` and explode the slashes.  Get the array value at index 1.

Comment: @Matthew Great minds think alike ^_^

Comment: What if the path is `apples/oranges/bananas/pineapples`?

Answer (score 6):

```
$path = explode("/", "apples/oranges/bananas");

echo $path[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could explode the string (assuming it is) and then get the correct index from the array. Like so:

```
$string = "apples/oranges/bananas";

$array = explode('/', $string);

echo $array[1]; //outputs oranges
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to show off array dereferencing in *PHP > 5.4*:

```
echo explode('/', 'apple/oranges/bananas')[1];
```

Comment: The syntax will be confusing to newbies but more experienced coders can appreciate the amount of piping/chaining that takes place on that one line.

Comment: Depending on their familiarity with other languages they might. But otherwise, agreed. And of course you have to be running PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
$path = 'apples/oranges/bananas';
```

you could do:

```
$dir = basename(dirname($path));
```

if you want to start from the end of the string, and should work on Windows, or

```
$dir = preg_match('|/([^/]*)|', $path, $m) ? $m[1] : false;
```

if you want to start at the beginning of the string, and will not work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always 3 words separated by 2 slashes?
if yes, you can try:

```
$mypath = explode('/', 'apple/oranges/bananas');
echo $mypath[1]; //gives oranges
```